# $(this).attr('id)) returns undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, this

I have this HTML code

```
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 no-padding">
                                        <button class="accordion active_alarms_modification_div" id="<?=$alarm->id?>" value="<?=$alarm->id?>">Keywords: "<?php echo $alarm->original_keywords ?>" - Activated on: <?=$alarm->creation_date?> </button>
                                        <div class="panel table-responsive">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 kp">
                                                <form>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 nor-inputs no-padding">
```

I cannot retrieve the values of id and value because I get "undefined" as a result. The "this" or "$(this)" element seems to be correctly evaluated in the same function because other operations are performed using it. Here the codes

```
$('.active_alarms_modification_div').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).on("click", function(evt) { 
        setTimeout(function(){ 

            /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
            to highlight the button that controls the panel */
            $(this).toggleClass('active');    // this is recognised, it properly refers to that div
 console.log("chart button id\n");
 console.log($(this).attr('value'));   // this result undefined
 console.log(this.value);          // this result undefined
 console.log($(this).attr('id'));  // this result undefined
 console.log(this.id);   // this result undefined


            /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
            var panel = $(this).next();   // this is recognised, it properly refers to the next inner div of active_alarms_modification_div
            if (panel.css("display") === "block") {
                panel.css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                panel.css('display', 'block');
                //window.charts[this.id].render();
            }

            }, 100);
    });

});
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**
The problem was the one highlighted in the remarks i.e. the fact that "this" in the timeout management refers to the "window" object and not anymore to the container div identified by the class "active_alarms_modification_div". I copy here the fixing solution in case somebody will find the same problem reading my question instead of the one indicated at the top of my question itself.

```
$('.active_alarms_modification_div').each(function(i, obj) {

    var div = this; // reference to the container div

    $(this).on("click", function(evt) { 
        setTimeout(function(){  // warning: in here (timeout) "this" referes to wiindow, not to the container div

            /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
            to highlight the button that controls the panel */
            $(div).toggleClass('active'); 

            /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
            //var panel = $(this).next();   // this is recognised, it properly refers to the next inner div of active_alarms_modification_div
            var panel = $(div).next();

            if (panel.css("display") === "block") {
                panel.css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                panel.css('display', 'block');
                window.charts[div.id].render();
            }

            }, 100);
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you try using obj instead of this?

Comment: Please ensure that element have Id by inspect the element. That jquery code is correct

Comment: @Keith in the same function this $(this).toggleClass('active');  is working. this $(this).attr('value')  and this  this.value not. I don't know alternatives; what do you mean with obj.

Comment: `this` in the timeout is a reference to the `window`, not the clicked element. You need to store a reference to it from the outer scope. See the duplicate for more information. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/k4zwgjh6/

Comment: @ Jayakumar Thangavel  this is the relative rendered part: <button class="accordion active_alarms_modification_div active" id="0" value="0"> does it appear correct? I cannot catch the problem...

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thanks I give a glance to the url you provided ... where can i find the duplicate link also?

Comment: It's at the top of the page

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thank you, suggestion fixed partially problem setting this

        var div = this;
        
        $(this).on("click", function(evt) { 
            setTimeout(function(){ 

But it works correctly just with first hidden division, still have problem with the second one. Besides, still I cannot understand why if in timeout "this" refers to windows this.toggleClass function changes 'active' just on active_alarms_modification_div div as well as this.next refers to the next child of active_alarms_modification_div!?

Comment: `I cannot understand why if in timeout "this" refers to windows this.toggleClass function changes 'active' just on active_alarms_modification_div` it doesn't. I'm not sure why you believe it does. Check the DOM with the inspector and you'll see that the `class` attribute of the target element does not change